# weaving .aj files into existing javac compiled sources

Tags: binary, aspectj, javac

I am trying to use javac to compile a set of java files to .class files and then subsequently use iajc to compile and weave all the aspects. My ant build.xml looks like this.

The compile part:

```
<target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source ">
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${target} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${target}" debug="true">
        <classpath refid="project.class.path" />
    </javac>
</target>
```

The iajc part:

```
<target name="aspects">
    <mkdir dir="dist"/>     
    <iajc source="1.6" target="${asptarget}">
        <inpath>
            <pathelement location="${target}"/>
        </inpath>
        <sourceroots>
            <fileset dir="${src}">
                <include name="**/*.aj"/>
            </fileset>
        </sourceroots>
         <classpath>
              <pathelement location="${aspectj.home}/lib/aspectjrt.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </iajc>
</target>
```

Judging by the error message, I am not getting this correct. The sourceroots are wrong!
How can I compile just the .aj files with aspectj and then binary weave the class files and compiled .aj files? Is that possible without recompiling all the original java sources too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the regular compiler for building .java files and iajc to build .aj files you do this:

```
<target name="aspects" depends="compile" description="build binary aspects">
    <fileset id="ajFileSet" dir="${src}" includes="**/*.aj"/>
    <pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}" property="ajFiles" refid="ajFileSet"/>
    <echo file="${src}/aj-files.txt">${ajFiles}</echo>

    <iajc source="1.6" target="${asptarget}">
        <argfiles>
            <pathelement location="${src}/aj-files.txt"/>
        </argfiles>

        <classpath>             
            <pathelement path="${target}"/>
            <fileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        </classpath>
         <classpath>
              <pathelement location="${aspectj.home}/lib/aspectjrt.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </iajc>
</target>
```

Works perfectly by building a file containing a list of the .aj files and compiling them. You can then use runtime OR binary weaving to finish the process.

Comment: can you help me , this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930247/when-run-ant-script-aspectj-not-import-aspect-source-folder-out-side-java-class